# ORACLE SQL Developer ORA-00904

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, project

first time using Oracle, need to create tables for my class project

Keep getting an error ORA - 00904 : invalid identifier
The following is my script. 
Any hints, tip, suggestions are welcome thank you!!

```
PROMPT 'Creating Table ZillowUserAccount'
CREATE TABLE zillowuseraccount
(
    zillowuseraccountid   VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    username              VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    password              VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    firstname             VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    lastname              VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    dob                   DATE,
    emailaddress          VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT zillowuseraccount_pk PRIMARY KEY ( zillowuseraccountid ),);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Developer is showing you the problem. Take a closer look.

[image]

Remove that comma, run again.

```
PROMPT 'Creating Table ZillowUserAccount'
CREATE TABLE zillowuseraccount
(
    zillowuseraccountid   VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    username              VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    password              VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    firstname             VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    lastname              VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    dob                   DATE,
    emailaddress          VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT zillowuseraccount_pk PRIMARY KEY ( zillowuseraccountid ));


'Creating Table ZillowUserAccount'

Table ZILLOWUSERACCOUNT created.
```

BTW, welcome to the wide world of Oracle, and good luck on your class project! You can use the Create Table dialog available from the connection tree as well. Just right-click on the Table node, and say New Table.

After you've done your 'work', you can see the code that was generated. So you can use the GUI to generate your project code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `comma` just after `CONSTRAINT ZillowUserAccount_PK PRIMARY KEY(zillowuseraccountID)` statement.